# Does changing the default schema for a user affect other open connections

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I can change the default schema of an existing SQL Server user [using the following T-SQL statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
ALTER USER Mary51 WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = Purchasing;
```

What happens to existing open connections with the user `Mary51` in this case?

- Does the old default schema remain in effect until the connection is closed?
- Or until the connection is returned to a connection pool?
- Or is it changed immediately?
- If it is changed immediately, what happens if another connection is in the middle of a transaction using the old default schema?

Comment: If it was explicitly documented anywhere, it'd be in `ALTER USER`, which as you've undoubtedly already noticed is not the case -- so the best way to answer these questions is by trying it out, while simultaneously not actually relying on the current behavior if it matters at all (in other words, always explicitly qualifying objects with a schema name, or explicitly killing sessions if you intend to change the schema). The default schema can be used to pull some occasionally useful tricks by redirecting access to unqualified objects, but that's not an actual design goal.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - thanks, but it will be difficult to get a conclusive result just by trying it out.  I agree that one should try to avoid relying on current undocumented behavior, and am mainly looking for additional information to back up my opinion that it's not a good idea.

Comment: I'd turn it around: why is this even being considered in the first place, what problem is it intended to solve? If there's an alternative where there's no question about the behavior in the first place because it *is* documented, that'd obviously be preferable, and I can think of a few, depending on the scenario (`SESSION_CONTEXT`, synonyms, views, dynamic SQL, proxies...). Even if it is *possible* to work out what will happen with schema changes (by experiment or additional clues in the docs), the net effects would likely be unpredictable/not guaranteeable *in practice*.

Comment: @Jeroen, I intend to do my best to turn it round, but I'm still interested in an answer to the question (though I accept that I may not get one).  The main issue is a reluctance to modify existing legacy code that uses unqualified object names, and I'm looking for as many arguments as possible to overcome that reluctance.